# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have image slider, and in IE I have an error.

This is my code:

```
*//Složka s obrázky partnerů
string slozka = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Partneri");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cislo_obrazku = 0;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ArrayList slide = new ArrayList();
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo inputDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(slozka);
        foreach (FileInfo eachfile in inputDir.GetFiles())
        {
            slide.Add(eachfile.ToString());
            cislo_obrazku += 1;
        }
        Session["cislo_obrazku"] = cislo_obrazku;
        Session["obrazky"] = slide;
        Casovac(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

protected void Casovac(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList slide = new ArrayList();
    slide = (ArrayList)Session["obrazky"];
    if ((Session["aktualni"] != null) && (Convert.ToInt32(Session["aktualni"]) != Convert.ToInt32(Session["cislo_obrazku"]) - 1))
    {
        //Posun na další
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~\\Partneri\\" + slide[Convert.ToInt32(Session["aktualni"]) + 1].ToString();
        Session["aktualni"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["aktualni"]) + 1;
    }
    else if (Session["aktualni"] == Session["cislo_obrazku"])
    {
        //Pokud není další, začni znovu
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~\\Partneri\\" + slide[0].ToString();
        Session["aktualni"] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["cislo_obrazku"]) != 0)
        {
            //Initally load the first image in the image control
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~\\Partneri\\" + slide[0].ToString();
            Session["aktualni"] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`

Error point to this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~\\Partneri\\" + slide[0].ToString();
```

and

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~\\Partneri\\" + slide[0].ToString();
```

Have you some idea?

Comment: This isn't classic asp.  You should tag it as asp.net and C#

Comment: Have you checked that slide[0] is not null?

Comment: Obviously, `slide` either `slide[0]` is `null`

Comment: Have you checked if Session["obrazky"] isn't null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NRE` is possibly the easiest exception to understand. It is also one of the most common problems when you have not coded defensively enough.

Quite simply, it means you are trying to access a property/method on an object which is null.

In your case

```
 slide[0].ToString();
```

either

- `slide` is null
- `slide[0]` is null.

Set a breakpoint, debug your app. Determine Which is null, and either account for that (eg, with a default) or throw a more meaningful exception if it truly is an exceptional circumstance for that object to be null.

Answer (score 0):

The session object `obrazky` has not been initialized.

Add a null check after:

```
slide = (ArrayList)Session["obrazky"];
```

Comment: `if (slide == null || slide[0] == null)`

Comment: Error again...i haven´t wrote all code, now the code on top is edited and its all...

Comment: where did you add the check?

Comment: under this...slide = (ArrayList)Session["obrazky"]; But i have the same error

Comment: and what do you do in the if statement?

Comment: you have to either assign a value to the slide or exit the method is the `if` condition evaluates to false.